# How to validate a no-namespace file using saxon with a defined namespace schema?

Tags: java, xsd, namespaces, saxon

I may have missed some obvious config options on Saxon, but here is my issue :

I have an xml file input.xml with no namespace declaration.
I have an xsd schema, schema.xsd associated with mynamespace namespace.
And I'd like to validate the input.xml file using Saxon and the schema.xsd file as if the root element of my input.xml file was in the mynamespace namespace ?
To ask it differently, I'd like to add the default namespace declaration xmlns="mynamespace" in the root element of input.xml but without opening it in Java and only for validation purpose.
Is it possible ? Is there any configuration option in Saxon which permit to declare a default namespace for the xml files to be validated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Saxon has a facility for converting a no-namespace document into a namespaced document: it's called XSLT.

If you want ultra-efficiency you could write a SAX filter that changes the namespace, and put this filter into your processing pipeline in front of the schema validator.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I didn't want to use XSLT because of efficiency, as you guessed. The SAX filter is an option, I'll try it. Or, I'll just switch my schema to an anonymous one.

Comment: In the case of a simple transformation like this, Saxon's processing time is dominated by the cost of XML parsing. Using SAX won't save you any significant processing time, though it may be worth it for the memory savings if the document is very large.